# How to get the exact year difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I need a simple way to find the exact year difference between two dates.
For example between 01.11.2013 and 30.10.2019. In this case, it should be 5 years because current date has not reached 01.11 yet. But if it is between 29.10.2013 and 30.10.2019 then it should be 6 years.

Let assume these are birthday and current days. It's similar.

I've tried to get the result with the following code:

```
select datediff(year,20131101,20191030)
```

It is giving me 6 instead of 5. The closest solution I've found is:

```
select datediff(day,20131101,20191030)/365
```

But as we know there could be 1 or 2 leap years in this period and the result is again not exactly what I expect. Neither when we divide with 365 nor 366.

It is not necessary using datediff. I wonder if there is some simple way to present it or some stored function to do this for which existing I did't know.

Comment: It all depends by the way you are passing the year. Where does it come from? What *type* will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the year difference and then subtract 1 if necessary:

```
select (datediff(year, val1, val2) -
        (case when month(val1) < month(val2) then 0
              when month(val1) > month(val2) then 1
              when day(val1) <= day(val2) then 0
              else 1
         end)
        ) as diff_years
```

Comment: It''s closest for what I'm looking for. I just wondered if there is some more simple way. Some stored function for which existing I don't know. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try datediff Month / 12.

```
  Declare @date1 Datetime
  Declare @date2 Datetime
  set @date1='2013-11-01 23:59:59'
  set @date2='2019-10-30 00:00:00'
(select (datediff(HOUR, @date1, @date2)/24/365 ) as diff_years)
```

Comment: But if it is between 20131029 and 20191028 the answer is still not correct

Comment: Yes you right I edited. @Gordon Linoff 's method look like more useful.

Comment: Much better now, but still the issue whit leap years.